# For statement treats i as a string not a number

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Can someone tell me why when I run the following code it places my "Syncing" string going into row 11 instead of row 2 (if it was the first option after the header).   Basically when I write i+1 it is making "11" and not the number "2";

```
  for (var i in usValues){
    var curEmail =   usValues[i][0];
    if (curEmail == myEmail){
     userSheet.getRange(i+1, 2).setValue("Snycing"); // going into column 11 instead of 2
    }
  }
```

It does work if I write it this way, but I get that efficiency bulb telling me to reduce the calls to getValue().

```
  for (var i= 1; i<=userSheet.getMaxRows(); i++){
   var curEmail =   userSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
    if (curEmail == myEmail){
     userSheet.getRange(i, 2).setValue("Snycing");
    }
  }
```

Comment: The second answer gives a far better solution (Jonathon) you were actually mixing 2 problems by changing 2 parameters altogether : loop index and spreadsheet service calls.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Right now your code concatenates strings. So `Var i` is considered a string, you must:

`var col = parseInt(i,10) + 1;`
`userSheet.getRange(col, 2).setValue("Snycing");`

---

The second parameter (10) in parseInt is for: 
radix [ - the second parameter] 
Optional. A value between 2 and 36 indicating the base of the number contained in [the first parameter]. If not supplied, strings with a prefix of '0x' are considered hexadecimal and strings with a prefix of '0' are considered octal. All other strings are considered decimal.

---

You could also:
Assign `var i = 0;` outside of your loop.
Or convert to number by using the `+` operator. So:

```
var i;
 for (+i in usValues){..} //I believe this should work
```

Comment: Thank you.  I knew I needed to change it to an integer, but I didn't know how.

Comment: This is a hack to work around an inappropriate array looping method.

Comment: How is it inappropriate and what way should I loop the array?

Comment: @BjornBehrendt take a look at Jonathon's answer. That will fix the root of your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You are accessing `usValues` as an object with the `for...in` notation. It is in fact an array, albeit 2D.

The `for...in` method returns the object keys as strings, which for an array are the zero start index values. This is why you are the concatenating the `+1` later.

You're right that the second model would be inefficient with get values within a loop, but its a better way of looping through the array. Using the 2d array you have already fetched:

```
var usValues = userSheet.get values(1,1,userSheet.getMaxRows(),2));
for (var i =0; i < usValues.length; i += 1){
  var curEmail = usValues[i][0];
  if (curEmail === myEmail){
   usValues[i][1] = "Syncing";
  }
}
userSheet
  .getRange(1,1,usValues.length,2)
  .set values(usValues)
```

Getting with one query and likewise setting with only one call. All the comparison logic just using standard js array values. Much quicker.